# Spring batch write exception with file parameters

Tags: spring-batch

I want to write the exceptions in the same file as the item writer but do not work

// MyLitner

```
public static class MySkipListener implements SkipListener<CSCiviqueDTO, CSCiviqueDTO> {

private BufferedWriter bw = null;

  public MySkipListener(File file) throws IOException {
     bw= new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
  }

    @Override
    public void onSkipInRead(Throwable throwable) {
        if (throwable instanceof FlatFileParseException) {
            FlatFileParseException flatFileParseException = (FlatFileParseException) throwable;
            System.out.println("onSkipInRead =========> :");
            try {
                bw.write(flatFileParseException.getInput() + "; Step Vérifiez les colonnes !!");
                bw.newLine();
                bw.flush();
                // fileWriter.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Unable to write skipped line to error file");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your listener is created with a given file. Is this file the same as the one used with your item writer?

Comment: Hello Mahmoud, no in different files then I merge them

Comment: In that case, you need an additional step that does the merge.